# Invalid deque <T> subscript . Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c++, deque, boost-unordered

I am getting the execption error in the following piece of code. Any suggestions on what might be causing it ?
`Error : Invalid deque <T> subscript`

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<HistObj> shared_hist_def;
        typedef std::deque<shared_hist_def> vector_def;
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<vector_def> shared_vector_def;
        typedef boost::unordered_map<int,shared_vector_def> in_map_def;
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<in_map_def> shared_inner_map_def;

Domain::shared_hist_def& Domain::GetSpecificHistoricalTuple(const std::string& symb,const int& tframe,const int& val)
{
    Domain::shared_inner_map_def tshare = stat_History_base[symb];
    shared_vector_def tmp = tshare->at(tframe);
    try
    {
        Domain::shared_hist_def safe_tuple =  tmp->at(val);
        return safe_tuple;
    }
    catch (std::exception &ex)
    {
        std::string a = ex.what();
        __debugbreak();
    }
}
```

**More information:**

The above method is a static method. And the program is multithreaded.Any chance that this error occurs because multiple threads access it. I had that assumption but then think that function parameters above could never be the same at one time.

Comment: just added to the post

Comment: I don't see the definition of `stat_History_base` but it isn't local to the function, so probably will cause problems with multithreading.

Comment: shared_ptr of the map where values are shared_ptrs of deque of shared_ptrs. Are you serious? My brains are blown...

Comment: is `val` negative? that's what you seem to be using to index the deque at `Domain::shared_hist_def safe_tuple =  tmp->at(val);`

Comment: @MarcClaesen what gives you the impression that val is negative ?

Comment: @MistyD I suspected `val` to be the cause of your errors, e.g. it's either too large or negative. If that's not it, I don't know what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Your `val` parameter seems to be too high (greater or equal to the number of elements in the `deque`), or maybe it's negative.

Comment: I always check my val parameter. when the exception occurs. Also the container does have the objects at index of val.

Comment: I am sorry, but how do you know the container does have the objects at index of `val` at the time of the exception? It looks like `at(val)` itself fails. Maybe checking/logging val and size just before calling `at` will show something. Also, if the program is multi-threaded, can there be any chance that one thread modifies the deque while another thread keeps the old index? (Running it single-threaded would show this.)

Comment: yeah I suspect that is the problem. That is why I am adding locks to my code